# What's the unit of measurement for weapon range?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack

How is range measured in D&D 5e? Is it by feet, like the movement speed, is it squares, like 4e, or something else entirely? I'm asking to calculate the range of a rifle.

Answer (score 14):

Ranges in the core rulebooks are listed in feet. In fact, squares are not used in D&D 5E at all, except in the optional grid rules presented in the Dungeon Master's Guide (one square = five feet).

That said, there are rules for firearms (including rifles) on page 268 of the Dungeon Master's Guide.

Answer (score 4):

It's measured in feet. For example in the PHB a short bow has a normal range of 80ft and a long range of 320ft. if you're using a gridded map than usually its one square = 5ft

But as far as I know the range is always in feet.

Answer (score 3):

The spells and weapons in D&D 5e's rules show their range in feet: not squares, not hexes.  That suggests to me that the game's authors intended to go back to the convention that requires neither grids nor hexes.

I'd recommend that you use polar coordinates: range for firearms and artillery is often judged in azimuth and distance.

Experience:

We used the same convention for range and direction in our D&D games as we used in our micro armor games, back in the day. (uh, starting 40 or so years ago and moving forward).  What we liked about it is that it freed us from hexes and squares on board games, which are an artificiality that is used to make a board game playable.

Our most recent D&D group used Roll20 and our DM was happy to let us use polar coordinates to figure out range (distance and direction) even though he had grid squares up for ease of keeping track of position during play.  It worked very well.

A piece of string and a ruler is the simplest mundane tool, if needed.

Interestingly, some early computer games based on RPG's used squares (such as Diabo I) but as computing power grew it switched to an approximation of polar coordinates (see Diablo II and III). It's more "realistic" that way.

Comment: I've never seen this used in any edition of D&D. Since bows and siege weapons are also ballistic weapons, wouldn't they also use a polar coordinate system if you are going to apply them to rifles? Also, this answer doesn't seem to either address the base question, nor give details on how such a system would be used in play or mesh with existing rules,

Comment: @keithcurtis  Shooting at that target deals with both direction and range measured in feet/inches/units of the day.  You don't have to measure the degrees, per se, but if you have three targets, the targets vary in their angular orientation to you, the shooter.  Go to sea and fire a naval gun.  Go to the shooting range, fire your rifle.  You are using polar coordinates (degrees(relative to the center(you, the shooter)) and distance).  I edited the answer to pull the point about the rules out from the middle of the text.  Experience based answers are valid.

Comment: @keithcurtis If you weren't using squares, you were using polar coordinates and didn't realize it.  Just shooting something "20 feet away" is meaningless: **what direction are you shooting it?**  That applies to ballistae and other siege engines (artillery) as well.

Comment: I'm interested in *how* exactly you use polar coordinates. The specific mechanics of how you would define and resolve attacks with polar coordinates.

Comment: @NicolBolas has it. KorvinStarmast, I understand range and azimuth. I've used polar coordinates in sci fi games to translate RAF & Dec to Euclidean for figuring star distances. I'm interested in how you use them mechanically **in the rule set**. I've never seen a system that models how high you point your bow to hit a target 60 feet away. It's always subsumed in the skill, like how you hold the point of your sword, or when you release a sling. How would you use azimuth as a game mechanic, specifically within D&D 5e?

Comment: @keithcurtis I think you are both missing the point.  Polar coordinates is what you are doing when you get rid of squares and hexes.  You return to distance and direction.  Would you rather I change the answer to read "distance and direction" from "polar coordinates?" if you feel that the term is confusing?

Comment: No, I think it's irrelevant to the question**"How is range measured in D&D 5e? Is it by feet, like the movement speed, is it squares, like 4e, or something else entirely?"** Other answers here have answered the question asked. i.e. "in D&D 5e, range is measured in feet, but can be counted in 5 foot squares if desired". Bringing in polar coordinates in no way satisfies the answer. At least not as far as I can see. Azimuth is expressed as an angle. I don't see any mention of how to use angles in your answer. How does this answer help the OP? He is specifically asking for range, not bearing.

Comment: @keithcurtis I removed reference to Polar Coordinates.  How did we use that mechanically?  Rulers and sticks, and pieces of string as the occasion called for it.    It really isn't that complicated.

Comment: I never said it was complicated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Range is measured using the imperial system. (Feet, yards, miles etc.) If you're using a map that uses squares for your roleplay, each square is five feet. So if you're shooting something with a hand crossbow for example, you can shoot at a minimum of 30 feet, divide 30 by five and you get six, so you can shoot at a minimum of six squares away.